# Segmentation fault when passing a pointer to an array into a function (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm trying to get a large array of random numbers, then pass that array into a function that will create a new array with 10 elements whose values correspond with the values in the large array. I pass the parameter **start** into the function to indicate the index of the large array from which I will start copying the values into the smaller array.

In case my explanation isn't clear, I have an array A of 20 randomly generated numbers: 
**A = {1, 2, 3, .... 20}**

I want to make an array B that holds the first 10 numbers:
**B = {1, 2, 3, .... 10}**

and an array C that holds the second 10: 
**C = {11, 12, 13, .... 20}**

I'm able to generate the random numbers and display them with a for loop, but once I start trying to make the new arrays I get a segmentation fault in terminal:
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Below is my code.

```
int main() {

    int size = 20;
    int *arrA = getRandomScores(size);

    int *arrB = applyScores(arrA, 0);
    int *arrC = applyScores(arrA, 10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << arrB[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << arrC[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int *applyScores(int *arr, int start) {
    int *newArr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[start];
        start++;
    }    

    return newArr;
}

int *getRandomScores(int size) {
    int *arr;

    //return null if size is zero or negative
    if (size <= 0)
        return NULL;

    //dynamically allocate the array
    arr = new int[size];

    //seed the random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    //populate the array with random numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;

    return arr;
}
```

I'm on linux, so I was told to use valgrind to see a more detailed error message. Below is what valgrind gave me. This is my first encounter with a segmentation fault, so forgive me if the answer is trivial with valgrind's help.

[valgrind error log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGgOa.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `newArr` as a pointer to `int`, but it points nowhere. You could create a new array like this:

```
int *newArr = new int[10];
```

but remember to delete the array when you are done with it:

```
delete[] arrB;
delete[] arrC;
```

Or you could simply use `std::vector<int>` for your arrays A,B and C (or at least B and C).

Answer (score 1):

you never allocate the memory for B and C

```
int *applyScores(int *arr, int start) {
    int *newArr = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[start];
        start++;
    }    

    return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As valgrind states (use of uninitialised value, which means the pointer and invalid write, which means write to where the pointer happens to refer to): you don't allocate memory to copy the random scores to `arrB` and `arrC`.  `arrNew` in `applyScores()` is just a pointer, so it can't store an array.  The easiest way to avoid this kind of problems is to use standard library containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`, which do what you expect and avoid manual memory management.